# What is the equivalent of onCreateOptionsMenu() for fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, menu

> To specify the options menu for an activity, override onCreateOptionsMenu() (fragments provide their own onCreateOptionsMenu() callback).

Recently while reading google docs I found this but there is no article for how to add menus in a fragment.

I just want to ask is there a way for this and if yes how should it be done. Please tell in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

There is a [link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=en#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater))

You have to override the same method as for Activity, but parameters differ a little comparing with Activity analogue:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.name_of_your_menu, menu)
}
```